# is there an algorithm that indexes spaces instead of characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays

New to this and was wondering after reading up on indexing and character counts. wouldn't it be more applicable to index spaces instead of characters to improve matching of words?

Looking at the example below, it selects/counts the white spaces at the end of every word. But I want it to count or recognize the space at the end of a word and the beginning of the following word, essentially noticing/collating white space characters. Does that make any sense?

```js
var str = 'This is a string',
    index = 0,
    res = [];

while ((index = str.indexOf(' ', index + 1)) > 0) {
  res.push(index);
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Can you show us some code, or describe a use-case for this? Just asking because your question may be closed due to criteria being "too broad"

Comment: Because you are expected to do `"hello world".split(" ")`.

Comment: like I said, new to this but even when you split, you are still indexing or counting the characters to get the position of a match. my question is in relation to words and eliminating each character count and just counting the white spaces to get a word match.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. What kind of application are you talking about? What do you mean by indexing spaces? What does this have to do with character counts? Can you show some example code that demonstrates what you're talking about?

Comment: var str = 'This is a string',
    index = 0,
    res = [];
while ((index = str.indexOf(' ', index + 1)) > 0) {
    res.push(index);
}
console.log(res) ////////////////// looking at this example, it selects/ counts the white spaces at the end of every word but I want it to count or recognize the space at the end of a word and the beginning of the following word. essentially noticing/collating white space characters. does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, but you can split it into an array of strings by spaces with [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Long answer:
You could think about this in a few ways... and this applies to more languages than just JS:

### Implementation

`Strings` are more akin to an array of characters. This is easier visualized if you think about how a `string` would be recognized by a computer: as a number (wait what?).

As I'm sure you know, computers can really only see `1`'s and `0`'s, so some smart people came up with a way to represent what character with what number... and then define some special things when some characters come in certain orders, but that's a whole other can of worms, these definitions are what we call charsets. Note that the number of bits available per character is defined by the charset i.e. `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`

So returning to the original question "Why index by characters and not spaces?": because <del>we're lazy and that was easy</del> it's actually pretty convenient for reasons I'm about to elaborate on.

### Mathematics

Let's be honest with ourselves, this is Computer *Science*, so we should probably back up our reasons with math... which is where [Formal Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) come in.

> A **formal language** L over an alphabet Σ is a subset of Σ*, that is, a set of words over that alphabet.
>
> A **formal grammar** is a set of production rules for strings in a formal language.
>
> A **word** over an alphabet can be any finite sequence (i.e., string) of letters.
>
> In mathematics a **sequence** is an enumerated collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed.

Note: Be aware that this post is in no way a proper description of formal languages, just a collection of generalized descriptions provided by wikipedia

Which leads me to grammars, your case of a string being indexed by a `" "` is really more of something that is defined as a grammar and is really a concept derived from <del>those nonsensical</del> human languages.

So what this means is if you boil down what a string really is and what defines it, you can see that it is defined all the way down on the level of mathematics.

### Practicality

But wait, I am human why does that still apply?

Well think about it this way, a `string` can hold more than just a sentence right? Take JSON for example `"{\"key1\":\"hello world\",\"key2\":0}"` would it make sense to have this string indexed by spaces? There's also the issue that substrings are a lot more tricky because we can't reference the individual characters anymore, so even iterating over a string would become a complicated task.

So why not make another data type?

Honestly this is just a reiteration of before: is it really necessary? Is it common enough of a problem to warrant an entirely new datatype when the key difference is more or less splitting the string and not allowing the programmer to look up the characters individually?

### An Algorithm

Well this is probably the easiest part of the answer... now that we have a general understanding of what a string is. As with all programming, there's a ton of way to go about it: I'm specifically sticking with JS functions, because that was tagged in the question.

As @Redu mentioned, there's the [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method (which is the easiest way I know of). Which allows you to split a string based on another string, or a regular expression (these are also defined in formal languages, most programming languages that have them have much more "featured" regular expressions, they can also be used to describe some grammars). So to split a string based on a `' '` we can do one of three ways (2 are regular expression approaches).

```js
console.log("Hello World!".split(" ")); // Split on all instances of a single space
console.log("Foo bar".split(/ /g)); // RegEx split on all single spaces
console.log("A  RegEx".split(/\s+/g)); // RegEx split on one or more whitespaces (not necessarily just a space)
console.log("A  RegEx".split(" ")); // For comparison (multiple spaces)
```

**TL;DR**

<del>Blame math</del> There are quite a few reasons, but essentially, it really doesn't make sense to.. why not split the `string`?